# Tsql a way to find empty tables without using sys. Partitions

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way I can find all empty tables in a database without using sys. Partition rows?

Comment: Why not use `sys.partitions`? If you are using an old SQL Server version like SQL Server 2000, add that tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT i.rowcnt, o.NAME
FROM sysindexes AS i
  INNER JOIN sysobjects AS o ON i.id = o.id 
WHERE i.indid < 2  AND OBJECTPROPERTY(o.id, 'IsMSShipped') = 0
AND i.rowcnt = 0
ORDER BY i.rowcnt desc
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the feed back. Sorry I'm still new to sql and stack overflow. So for verification this query will show me all the tables in a database that currently has no records and is complete empty right

Comment: yes this will give the result row set for all the tables that has no any row inserted.